# Yet another viewstate dropdownlist issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, viewstate

I have the following code in the `Page_Load` method of a web form:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CountrySelectButton.Click += new EventHandler(CountrySelectButton_Click);

    if (HomePage.EnableCountrySelector) //always true in in this case
    {
        if(!IsPostBack)
            BindCountrySelectorList();
    }
}
```

The `BindCountrySelectorList` method looks like this:

```
private void BindCountrySelectorList()
{
    NameValueCollection nvc = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(HomePage.CountryList);

    var ds = nvc.AllKeys.Select(k => new { Text = k, Value = nvc[k] });

    CountrySelector.DataSource = ds;
    CountrySelector.DataTextField = "Text";
    CountrySelector.DataValueField = "Value";
    CountrySelector.DataBind();
}
```

And I have a `LinkButton` click event handler which gets the `SelectedValue` from the `SelectList` as so:

```
void CountrySelectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //get selected
    string selectedMarket = CountrySelector.SelectedValue; //this is always the first item...

    //set cookie
    if (RememberSelection.Checked)
        Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("blah_cookie", selectedMarket) { Expires = DateTime.MaxValue });

    //redirect
    Response.Redirect(selectedMarket, false);
}
```

**EDIT:**

This is the DDL and LinkButton definition:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="CountrySelector" />
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="CountrySelectButton" Text="Go" />
```

Resulting markup:

```
<select name="CountrySelector" id="CountrySelector">
    <option value="http://google.com">UK</option>
    <option value="http://microsoft.com">US</option>
    <option value="http://apple.com">FR</option>
</select>
<a id="CountrySelectButton" href="javascript:__doPostBack('CountrySelectButton','')">Go</a>
```

**END EDIT**

ViewState is enabled but the `SelectedValue` property only ever returns the first item in the list regardless of which item is actually selected. I'm certain I'm missing something obvious but I can't find the problem; any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Dave

Comment: @MikeSmithDev - Anything in particular you'd like to see? This is all the code behind is doing so I'm not sure what else I can offer.

Comment: Yes, the code front for your select list. More on event handler for LinkButton. Link button code front. Have you debugged through to see what is happening, like somehow you are rebinding somewhere?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev - I've added the DDL and LinkButton code. I removed everything else from the event handler and checked the SelectedValue while debugging to ensure it wasn't caused by any other action. I can't see anywhere it may be re-binding again but it's a valid question so I'll go back over the code and check...

Comment: Could you paste the resulting html of the dropdown list? It might give more insight to what actually is written to the client. The problem might occur in that step of the process.

Comment: Your code would work if this is all you are doing. I'm suspecting there is more going on you aren't showing... like how the ID changed from "SelectList" to "CountrySelector". Default renaming of IDs for runat=server tags would look more like <select name="ctl00$MainContent$SelectList" id="MainContent_SelectList">

Comment: @MikeSmithDev - I was trying to keep the names/id's generic for the purpose of the question but this has proved counter-productive so i've edited the question with more information and maintained the id's as they are set in my solution.

Comment: I'm at a loss. What you are showing should work fine. Last ditch - can you post the resulting html of DDL after postback? If all you are doing is setting cookie and redirect... could do fully in javascript and not even postback.

Comment: Your comment on the ID set me thinking, the most important part of the puzzle, and something I overlooked, was that these elements are appearing in a jquery modal dialog! jquery dialog is moving it all outside of the form element so .net has no idea what has happened with the dropdownlist!

Comment: @MikeSmithDev - Thanks for seeing this one through, can you add an answer as you absolutely deserve the credit for this one. Truly appreciate your time and effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that your issue stems from the jquery ui dialog... you can get around this by using a hidden field to record the value of the dropdownlist. Then in your code, reference the hidden field.

Front end could look like:

```
<div id="myModal" style="display: none;">
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="SelectList" />
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="MyButton" Text="Go" />
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="countryVal" runat="server" />
    <a id="choose" href="#">Choose</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#choose').click(function () {
                $('#myModal').dialog({
                });
                return false;
            });

            $('#<%= SelectList.ClientID %>').change(function () {
               var country = $(this).val();
               $('#<%= countryVal.ClientID %>').val(country);
            });
        }); 
    </script>
```

Then your code behind:

```
var selected = countryVal.Value;
```

Comment: If you use a hidden field you have to perform additional validation that you already get if you stick with the DropDownList. An alternative would just be to bind `$(document).on('submit', function() ...` grab the jQuery modal container, and append it back into the `<form>`.  jQuery modal moves your input elements outside the `<form>` element, that is why values don't behave how you expected them to.

Comment: Nice suggestion. I'll need to check that out.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the MyButton.Click+=... statement inside (!IsPostBack) like

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
   MyButton.Click += new EventHandler(MyButton_Click);
   BindSelectList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this stops my button from having its event bound on postback and hasn't helped the problem at hand.